# Animate points with labels with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot-annotations

I've got an animation with lines and now I want to label the points.
I tried `plt.annotate()` and I tried `plt.text()` but the labes don't move.
This is my example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, data, line):
    newData = np.array([[1+num,2+num/2,3,4-num/4,5+num],[7,4,9+num/3,2,3]])
    line.set_data(newData)
    plt.annotate('A0', xy=(newData[0][0],newData[1][0]))
    return line,


fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[7,4,9,2,3]])
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 20)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.annotate('A0', xy=(data[0][0], data[1][0]))
# plt.text( data[0][0], data[1][0], 'A0')

line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
    interval=200, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Can you help me please?

My next step is:
I have vectors with origin in these Points. These vectors change their length and their direction in each animation step.
How can I animate these?

Without animation this works:

```
soa =np.array( [ [data[0][0],data[1][0],F_A0[i][0][0],F_A0[i][1][0]],
               [data[0][1],data[1][1],F_B0[i][0][0],F_B0[i][1][0]],
               [data[0][2],data[1][2],F_D[i][0][0],F_D[i][1][0]] ])
X,Y,U,V = zip(*soa)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(X,Y,U,V,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1)
```

First thanks a lot for your fast and very helpful answer!

My Vector animation problem I have solved with this:

```
annotation = ax.annotate("C0", xy=(data[0][2], data[1][2]), xycoords='data',
    xytext=(data[0][2]+1, data[1][2]+1), textcoords='data',
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
```

and in the 'update-function' I write:

```
annotation.xytext = (newData[0][2], newData[1][2])
annotation.xy = (data[0][2]+num, data[1][2]+num)
```

to change the start and end position of the vectors (arrows).

But what is, wehn I have 100 vectors or more? It is not practicable to write:

```
annotation1 = ...
annotation2 = ...
    .
    :
annotation100 = ...
```

I tried with a list:

```
...
annotation = [annotation1, annotation2, ... , annotation100]
...

def update(num):
    ...
    return line, annotation
```

and got this error:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axes'

What can I do? Have you any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the return all objects that changed from your update function. So since your annotation changed it's position you should return it also:

```
line.set_data(newData)
annotation = plt.annotate('A0', xy=(newData[0][0],newData[1][0]))
return line, annotation
```

You can read more about `matplotlib` animations in [this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)

You should also specify the `init` function so that the `FuncAnimation` knows which elements to remove from the plot when redrawing on the first update. So the full example would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Create initial data
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [7,4,9,2,3]])

# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 20), ylim=(0, 20))

# Create initial objects
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'r-')
annotation = ax.annotate('A0', xy=(data[0][0], data[1][0]))
annotation.set_animated(True)

# Create the init function that returns the objects
# that will change during the animation process
def init():
    return line, annotation

# Create the update function that returns all the
# objects that have changed
def update(num):
    newData = np.array([[1 + num, 2 + num / 2, 3, 4 - num / 4, 5 + num],
                        [7, 4, 9 + num / 3, 2, 3]])
    line.set_data(newData)
    # This is not working i 1.2.1
    # annotation.set_position((newData[0][0], newData[1][0]))
    annotation.xytext = (newData[0][0], newData[1][0])
    return line, annotation

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=25, init_func=init,
                               interval=200, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can use `annotation.xytext = (newData[0][0], newData[1][0])` to update the position of the annotation.

Comment: Thank you @nordev, update the example. But why is `annotation.set_position((newData[0][0], newData[1][0]))` not working? It's documented as "Set the (*x*, *y*) position of the text". `xytext` is documented as a getter :-/

Comment: I use annotation.set_position() inside a function of my class and it works

Comment: Weird, which version of `matplotlib` do you use? Maybe they fixed it or broke it :D

Comment: I use matplotlib.__version__ '1.1.1'

Comment: Huh, now you tell me :D I already submitted an issue :D What have you changed so I can test it in the 1.2.1

Comment: @Victor I am also attempting to return a list of objects `pyplot.text` and `matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox`, and I recive the same error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'axes'`. Was the OP's problem fixed by this? In the update function I am resetting the position for each and still receive this error. Is it possible to return lists of these objects? Thanks.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez How's this an answer to your question? I'm running into the same problem right now. I've got a dynamic number of vectors that I'd like to animate with annotations. I cannot return a `list` of `annotation` objects. I end up getting the error message `'list' object has no attribute 'set_animated'`. Do you have any update on how to animate multiple annotation objects? Thanks!

Comment: Why `annotation.set_animated(True)`?  `annotation` is returned from both `init()` and `update(num)` and this should be sufficient, right?

Answer (score 15):

I'm coming here from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48674542/2454357), where an annotation should be updated that uses both `xy` and `xytext`. It appears that, in order to update the annotation correctly, one needs to set the *attribute* `.xy` of the annotation to set the position of the annotated point and to use the `.set_position()` *method* of the annotation to set the position of the annotation. Setting the `.xytext` attribute has no effect -- somewhat confusing in my opinion. Below a complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])

L = 50
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,L)
r = np.ones_like(theta)

x = r*np.cos(theta)
y = r*np.sin(theta)

line, = ax.plot(1,0, 'ro')

annotation = ax.annotate(
    'annotation', xy=(1,0), xytext=(-1,0),
    arrowprops = {'arrowstyle': "->"}
)

def update(i):

    new_x = x[i%L]
    new_y = y[i%L]
    line.set_data(new_x,new_y)

    ##annotation.xytext = (-new_x,-new_y) <-- does not work
    annotation.set_position((-new_x,-new_y))
    annotation.xy = (new_x,new_y)

    return line, annotation

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, update, interval = 500, blit = False
)

plt.show()
```

The result looks something like this:

[image: result of the above code]

In case that versions matter, this code has been tested on Python 2.7 and 3.6 with matplotlib version 2.1.1, and in both cases setting `.xytext` had no effect, while `.set_position()` and `.xy` worked as expected.

Comment: Yep, since `'Annotation' object has no attribute 'xytext'`, `annotation.xytext` is simply not expected to work at all.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest good point, a simple `dir(annotation)` actually reveals that. I wonder at which point this has changed. Apparently in older versions it was still around. Another thing worth noting is that `blit = True` does not produce the expected result in window mode. At least for me it shows a static annotation with the original coordinates and a rotating one on top. However [this github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6332/) recommends not to use blitting if no performance issues are encountered, so maybe it's ok.

Comment: When you set `blit=True` you need to return both artists, `return line,annotation,`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I actually do (I edited the code after first posting), but the problem remains. Anyway, it doesn't bother me, I just wanted to point that out. According to the github issue, when saving an animation to disk, the entire figure is redrawn every frame anyway.

Comment: Works fine for me. Could be a macos thing again?

Comment: This answer helped me immensely with a similar problem, but only after I added 'annotation_clip=False' to the 'annotate' call. Otherwise, it looked like there were missing arrows in the resulting movie, once I saved it out. (Python3.6, matplotlib 2)

Comment: @heisenBug according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html), annotations get clipped when the value for the `xy` keyword is outside the drawing area *and* `xycoords` is something else than `'data'`. In that case, setting `annotation_clip=False` should help making the annotation visible again. Did you try any other solutions, like, e.g., increasing the x- and y-limits of the Axes you are plotting in?

Comment: Increasing the limits would have also worked, but I was plotting an arrow on top of an image with a fixed size. In my case, having the arrows go slightly outside the image axes was preferable to changing the arrow or axes size.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out how to animate multiple annotations through a list. First you just create your annotations list:

```
for i in range(0,len(someMatrix)):
     annotations.append(ax.annotate(str(i), xy=(someMatrix.item(0,i), someMatrix.item(1,i))))
```

Then in your "animate" function you do as you have already written:

```
for num, annot in enumerate(annotations):
    annot.set_position((someMatrix.item((time,num)), someMatrix.item((time,num))))
```

(You can write it as a traditional for loop as well if you don't like the enumerate way). Don't forget to return the whole annotations list in your return statement.

Then the important thing is to set "blit=False" in your FuncAnimation:

```
animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames="yourframecount",
                          interval="yourpreferredinterval", blit=False, init_func=init)
```

It is good to point out that blit=False might slow things down. But its unfortunately the only way I could get animation of annotations in lists to work...