# How to animate labels corresponding to a scatter plot

Tags: python, list, animation

Previous questions that have asked how to animate an annotation have used a predefined equation were the annotation animation is reproducible. This question asks to find and return an xy coordinate at each time point so an annotation can be made in that spot.

I have an animated scatter plot that shows the XY co-ordinates of certain subjects.

A sample dataset is shown below:

```
Time    Player 1_X  Player 1_Y  Player 2_X  Player 2_Y  Player 3_X  Player 3_Y  Player 4_X
10:39.2 65.7        45.1        -2.2        -5.0        73.7        -3.5        61.9
10:39.3 65.8        45.2        -2.2        -5.0        73.7        -3.3        61.7
10:39.4 65.8        45.2        -2.2        -5.0        73.6        -3.2        61.7
10:39.5 65.8        45.3        -2.2        -5.1        73.6        -3.0        61.5
10:39.6 65.8        45.3        -2.1        -5.1        73.5        -2.9        61.3
10:39.7 65.8        45.4        -2.1        -5.2        73.5        -2.9        61.2
10:39.8 65.7        45.6        -2.2        -5.2        73.4        -2.7        61.1
10:39.9 65.7        45.6        -2.2        -5.2        73.3        -2.5        61.0
10:40.0 65.7        45.9        -2.3        -5.3        73.3        -2.5        60.9
10:40.1 65.7        46.1        -2.3        -5.3        73.3        -2.4        60.7
```

The code to animate these XY coordinates is shown below. I have tried to add an annotation to the first player's animated scatter plot but can't seem to get it working.

I'm hoping that each frame would show the XY data point and the corresponding name. So Player 1 would be labelled above the XY Coordinate of Player 1 at each time point.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

visuals = [[],[],[]]

with open('Wide_Single_timestamp2.csv') as csvfile :
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    n=0
    for row in readCSV :
        if n == 0 :
            n+=1
            continue
        visuals[0].append(list(map(float, row[3::2])))
        visuals[1].append(list(map(float, row[2::2])))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
plt.grid(False)

scatter = ax.scatter(visuals[0][0], visuals[1][0], c=['blue'], alpha = 0.7, s = 20, edgecolor = 'black', zorder = 1) #Scatter plot
annotation = ax.annotate('Player 1', xy=(visuals[0][0],visuals[1][0]))


def animate(i) : 
    scatter.set_offsets([[[[[visuals[0][0+i][0], visuals[1][0+i][0]], [visuals[0][0+i][1], visuals[1][0+i][1]], [visuals[0][0+i][2], visuals[1][0+i][2]], [visuals[0][0+i][3], visuals[1][0+i][3]]]]]])
    annotation.xytext = ([[visuals[0][0+i][0], visuals[1][0+i][0]]])
    annotation.set_data(annotation)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                      interval = 10, blit = False)
```

In addition, is there a way to offset the annotation because if it did use the corresponding xy coordinate the annotation would overlap the scatter plot as the annotation and scatter plot would be the same xy coordinate?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48418108/2454357) helps you. The title of the question is a bit misleading, but the answer shows how to change the position of an annotation.

Comment: It shows how to do it with a predefined equation. Not from a list were each time point is different. Thanks for the lead in. I'll aim to adapt it.

Comment: @ThomasKühn, I've adapted the code above but can't seem to get it working. Also if I added the label using the xy coordinate, wouldn't the scatter plot be redundant as the label would be using the same position on the plot. Is there a way to offset the annotation?