# Animate a annotation from a list of XY Coordinates

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, annotations

I am trying to animate annotations from a list of xy coordinates. The code below animates the `annotation` line but I cannot get the `arrow` function to animate using the same code.

The example dataset is a representation of the data I'm using. It is horizontally formatted. With this, I make a list from all the X-Coordinates and all the Y-Coordiantes from each subject. I then make a list pertaining to each time point, which is each row of data. From that I can plot a scatter and annotations.

However, when trying to plot an arrow between two separate coordinates I run into the error as stated by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. The function should be a tuple of two elements but I'm having trouble with the arrow animation function as I think I need to provide 4 elements. The X and Y coordinate for the first point and X and Y coordinate for the second point.

Will I have to re-format that data or is there a way to animate the arrow function were 4 tuples are required?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))
y_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))

lists = [[],[]]
lists[0] = x_data
lists[1] = y_data 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
ax.set_xlim(0,80)
ax.set_ylim(0,80)

scatter = ax.scatter(lists[0][0], lists[1][0], zorder = 5) #Scatter plot

annotation = ax.annotate('  Subject 1', xy=(lists[0][0][2],lists[1][0][2]))

arrow = ax.annotate('', xy = (lists[0][0][0], lists[1][0][0]), xytext = (lists[0][0][1],lists[1][0][1]), arrowprops = {'arrowstyle': "<->"})

def animate(i) : 
    scatter.set_offsets([[[[[lists[0][0+i][0], lists[1][0+i][0]], [lists[0][0+i][1], lists[1][0+i][1]], [lists[0][0+i][2], lists[1][0+i][2]], [lists[0][0+i][3], lists[1][0+i][3]]]]]])
    Subject_x = lists[0][0+i][2]
    Subject_y = lists[1][0+i][2]
    annotation.set_position((Subject_x, Subject_y))
    annotation.xy = (Subject_x, Subject_y)
    Arrow1 = (lists[0][0+i][0], lists[1][0+i][0]) #Code for arrow animation doesn't work. Produces a blank screen after the 1st frame
    Arrow2 = (lists[0][0+i][1], lists[1][0+i][1])
    arrow.set_position((Arrow1, Arrow2))
    arrow.xy = (Arrow1, Arrow2)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                          interval = 50, blit = False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The duplicate shows how to position annotations. If there is a problem with that you need to clearly state why the soltion does not work here. Since you haven't even tried to use the `.xy` and `.xytext` properties, we would simply close this as dupe again.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I was just in the process of writing an answer. Actually setting `.xytext` does not seem to work, but `.set_position()` does, while setting `.xy` has the desired effect -- somewhat confusing, if you ask me.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Can you write that answer to the duplicate? There in the answer there is a comment about set_position not working, so it would be good to have the working solution at the place where it belongs.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the answer is now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684902/2454357)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The `.set_position` and `.xy` work well for the `annotation` code but not for the `arrow` code. I can't seem to get the arrow between coordinates to animate. I've updated the question to highlight the error.

Comment: The answer to the duplicate shows how to animate the annotation (with or without the arrow). If that does not work for you, provide a [mcve] of the issue. Please use the @ notation to notify someone about the edit once it's done.

Comment: This is btw not the same code. You cannot set the position to a tuple of tuples.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the error was in that line. So I need to adjust `Length_max` and `Length_min`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, can I post a question asking how I would change the code to not include a tuple of tuples. The `xy` and `xytext` in the `ax.annotate` call require 4 different coordinates as they're sought from separate lists. Would this still be a duplicate question?

Comment: Both `xy` and `set_position` require a tuple of two elements `(x,y)`. This is clear from the duplicate, as well as from your working part of the code. It is hence equally clear that if you provide something other than that, like `((x1,y1),(x2,y2))`, it will not work. So the answer here is still to use the method from the duplicate, where a single coordinate pair is given to those attributes.

Comment: Since the code is not a [mcve], we don't have any chance finding out why you possibly think you need more coordinates here. I guess if you provide a [mcve] and precisely explain the role of those lists used and the expected outcome, it might become answerable.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Does this question suffice or I should I still be able to use the code provided in the original question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this is still given in this question:
[Animate points with labels with mathplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351932/animate-points-with-labels-with-mathplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1)

As said several times in the comments, each position is determined by a tuple of two values `(x,y)`. Hence you cannot provide a tuple of tuples to those positions. Also the start and end of the arrow should of course be at different positions.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))
y_data = np.random.randint(80, size=(400, 4))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
ax.set_xlim(0,80)
ax.set_ylim(0,80)

scatter = ax.scatter(x_data[0], y_data[0], zorder = 5) #Scatter plot

annotation = ax.annotate('  Subject 1', xy=(x_data[0,2],y_data[0,2]))

arrow = ax.annotate('', xy = (x_data[0,0], y_data[0,0]), 
                        xytext = (x_data[0,1],y_data[0,1]), 
                        arrowprops = {'arrowstyle': "<->"})

def animate(i) : 
    scatter.set_offsets(np.c_[x_data[i,:], y_data[i,:]])

    annotation.set_position((x_data[i,2], y_data[i,2]))

    start = (x_data[i,0], y_data[i,0]) 
    end   = (x_data[i,1], y_data[i,1])
    arrow.set_position(start)
    arrow.xy = end

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(x_data), 
                              interval = 700, blit = False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. Confusing myself thinking the start position would still read as a tuple of tuples.